# How to generate random values between -1/2 to 1/2

Tags: java, math, random

I am trying to figure out a way to generate random values between 1/2 and -1/2.

I tried something as below, but not sure if this is a right way to do it....

Can someone please let me know a good way to implement this?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        double Max = .5;
        double Min = -0.5;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            double value = Min + ((Math.random()) * (Max - Min));
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just generate random integers between 1 and some large number n, and multiply by point-1000 or something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) returns a random double between `0` and `1`, so to change the range to `-1/2` to `1/2`, we can just subtract `1/2` (since `0 - 1/2 = -1/2` and `1 - 1/2 = 1/2`):

```
Math.random() - 0.5
```

---

What you are doing now is more general, i.e. if you want a double between `min` and `max` the appropriate expression would be

```
min + Math.random() * (max - min)
```

In this case, plugging in `min = -0.5` and `max = 0.5` we have

```
-0.5 + Math.random() * (0.5 - -0.5)
```

which simplifies to

```
Math.random() - 0.5
```

---

I should also mention that, if you read the `random()` method's documentation, you will find that it returns a double *greater than or equal* to 0.0 and *less than* 1.0. This means that the expression above should produce a number in the range `[-0.5, 0.5)`, meaning that `-0.5` can potentially be returned but `0.5` cannot be.

Comment: note that the range will be [-1/2,1/2). It won't ever choose exactly 1/2, but it will choose -1/2

Comment: If you wanted (-1/2, 1/2], you could do 0.5 - x instead of x - 0.5

Answer (score 5):

You could just do:

```
Math.random() - 0.5
```

This is because the min of `Math.random()` is 0, and the max is 1. If you subtract a half, the min will be `0 - 0.5 == -0.5` and the max will be `1 - 0.5 == 0.5`.

Therefore, your original code can be shortened to:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        double value = Math.random() - 0.5; // no need for a "double" cast,
                                            // Math.random() returns a double
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the Math.Random() class is going to return a value between 0 and 1, not including 1.

In this case, `Math.Random()-0.5` will work sweetly